# SpringBootTest and MockMvc creating an enormous amount of console logging - how to disable?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, logging, spring-test

We're using `@SpringBootTest` with an `@Autowired private MockMvc mockMvc` attribute to mock HTTP requests to our controller classes.

For some reason that we can't seem to determine, this is creating enormous amounts of logging for each test case, and is filling our logs with *thousands* of lines of text that looks like:

```
build   18-May-2019 03:09:40    Async:
build   18-May-2019 03:09:40        Async started = false
build   18-May-2019 03:09:40         Async result = null
build   18-May-2019 03:09:40    
build   18-May-2019 03:09:40    Resolved Exception:
build   18-May-2019 03:09:40                 Type = null
build   18-May-2019 03:09:40    
build   18-May-2019 03:09:40    ModelAndView:
build   18-May-2019 03:09:40            View name = null
build   18-May-2019 03:09:40                 View = null
build   18-May-2019 03:09:40                Model = null
build   18-May-2019 03:09:40    
build   18-May-2019 03:09:40    FlashMap:
build   18-May-2019 03:09:40           Attributes = null
build   18-May-2019 03:09:40    
build   18-May-2019 03:09:40    MockHttpServletResponse:
build   18-May-2019 03:09:40               Status = 200
build   18-May-2019 03:09:40        Error message = null
build   18-May-2019 03:09:40              Headers = {X-Content-Type-Options=[nosniff], X-XSS-Protection=[1; mode=block], Cache-Control=[no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate], Pragma=[no-cache], Expires=[0], X-Frame-Options=[DENY]}
build   18-May-2019 03:09:40         Content type = null
build   18-May-2019 03:09:40                 Body = 
build   18-May-2019 03:09:40        Forwarded URL = null
build   18-May-2019 03:09:40       Redirected URL = null
build   18-May-2019 03:09:40              Cookies = []
build   18-May-2019 03:09:40    
build   18-May-2019 03:09:40    MockHttpServletRequest:
build   18-May-2019 03:09:40          HTTP Method = POST
build   18-May-2019 03:09:40          Request URI = /api/v1/certification/applications
build   18-May-2019 03:09:40           Parameters = {}
build   18-May-2019 03:09:40              Headers = {Content-Type=[application/json;charset=UTF-8]}
build   18-May-2019 03:09:40                 Body = {"applicationVersion":"1.0"}
build   18-May-2019 03:09:40        Session Attrs = {}
build   18-May-2019 03:09:40    
build   18-May-2019 03:09:40    Handler:
build   18-May-2019 03:09:40                 Type = <redacted>
build   18-May-2019 03:09:40               Method = <redacted>
build   18-May-2019 03:09:40    
build   18-May-2019 03:09:40    Async:
build   18-May-2019 03:09:40        Async started = false
build   18-May-2019 03:09:40         Async result = null
build   18-May-2019 03:09:40    
build   18-May-2019 03:09:40    Resolved Exception:
build   18-May-2019 03:09:40                 Type = null
build   18-May-2019 03:09:40    
build   18-May-2019 03:09:40    ModelAndView:
build   18-May-2019 03:09:40            View name = null
build   18-May-2019 03:09:40                 View = null
build   18-May-2019 03:09:40                Model = null
build   18-May-2019 03:09:40    
build   18-May-2019 03:09:40    FlashMap:
build   18-May-2019 03:09:40           Attributes = null
build   18-May-2019 03:09:40    
build   18-May-2019 03:09:40    MockHttpServletResponse:
build   18-May-2019 03:09:40               Status = 200
build   18-May-2019 03:09:40        Error message = null
build   18-May-2019 03:09:40              Headers = {X-Content-Type-Options=[nosniff], X-XSS-Protection=[1; mode=block], Cache-Control=[no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate], Pragma=[no-cache], Expires=[0], X-Frame-Options=[DENY]}
build   18-May-2019 03:09:40         Content type = null
build   18-May-2019 03:09:40                 Body = 
build   18-May-2019 03:09:40        Forwarded URL = null
build   18-May-2019 03:09:40       Redirected URL = null
build   18-May-2019 03:09:40              Cookies = []
```

All of my internet searching and Spring Boot Test documentation reading has been fruitless. **Where is this logging** coming from, and how can we turn it off?

We've scanned our code exhaustively, and are confident that we're not printing/responsible for it.

Comment: Do you have logback.xml file in your project ?

Comment: @Sambit No, there's no `logback.xml` anywhere in our project (we're using SLF4j with Log4j2), and a `mvn dependency:tree` of our project also lists no logback dependencies - direct, or transitive.

Comment: If you are using log4j2, in the xml, you can disable logging from a particular package.

Comment: I came across your question as I was working on [a similar issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56294762/how-to-print-only-the-requests-of-the-failed-test-with-autoconfiguremockmvc) you might as well be interested in, i.e. the same output being produced on failure.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is coming from `MockMvc`.

It would appear that you may have overridden the default and instructed Spring Boot to always print the debug output for `MockMvc`.

You should be able to deactivate this by declaring `@AutoConfigureMockMvc(printOnlyOnFailure = true)` or by omitting the `printOnlyOnFailure` flag since `true` is the default value.

You configure the output mode via the `print` attribute -- for example, `@AutoConfigureMockMvc(print = MockMvcPrint.NONE)`.

Answer (score 1):

You have to disable info logger from spring framework package in application.properties. Add the below property in application.properties.

```
logging.level.org.springframework=OFF
```

Comment: This will not work if `@AutoConfigureMockMvc` is not configured with `print = MockMvcPrint.LOG_DEBUG`. Moreover you may want to only disable `org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result` instead.